# I'm beginner in Android testing with Mockito

Tags: android, testing, mockito

I want to test this method using mockito and unit testing

public class CurrentIP {

```
public static String getIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                    boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':') < 0;
                    if (isIPv4)
                        return sAddr;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Now it is impossible because your dependency (NetworkInterface) is static so you are not able to replace if with mocked one and provide your own list of network interfaces.

Comment: if i have class with static methods one of them public and other private ex:HttpService.sendRequest(); other method pivate getRequest,PostRequest and others how to test this

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `IpAddressProvider` and `NetworkInterfaceProvider`.

Let `NetworkInterfaceProvider` has one method `getNetworkInterfaces()` which returns `List<NetworkInterfaces>` from `NetworkInterface`.

Let `NetworkInterfaceProvider` be a dependency of `IpAddressProvider` which is passed via constructor and stored in private field `ipAddressProvider`.

Let `IpAddressProvider` has a public method `getIPAddress()` in which it calls `ipAddressProvider.getNetworkInterfaces()` and does the processing you are doing in the static method you have posted.

Now you can test method `getIPAddress` of `IpAddressProvider` by providing fake instance of `NetworkInterfaceProvider` where you provide mocked list of NetworkInterfaces which you are in control of.

```
mockedIpAddressProvider = Mockito.mock(NetworkInterfaceProvider.class);
ipAddressProviderWhichYouWantToTest = IpAddressProvider(mockedIpAddressProvider);
```

For example:

In your test you hardcode your fake instance of `NetworkInterfaceProvider` to return an empty list.

`Mockito.when(mockedIpAddressProvider.getNetworkInterfaces()).thenReturn(emptyList)`

Then you expect `getIPAddress()` method to return empty String

`assertEquals("",ipAddressProviderWhichYouWantToTest.getIPAddress());`

Comment: but i want getIPAddress() static to easly access it to another place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832408/i-want-to-test-private-static-method-in-this-class-with-one-only-public-method   this my hall class and fun that i  want to test

Comment: you can use singleton pattern to make it easily accessible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837148/i-want-to-test-static-method-in-class-with-mockito iam try to isolate logic in function to test it this class is simple more than first one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832408/i-want-to-test-private-static-method-in-this-class-with-one-only-public-method   convert it to singlton but how to test it

Comment: It is not possible to test it while there are static dependencies. It is bad design which cannot be tested.

Comment: if you can help me to enhance this class and related method to be testable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832408/testing-a-private-static-method-in-a-class-with-one-only-public-method

Comment: Check my answer, you should organize your code in similar way so you can mock parts of it and test it.